# Does spacetime have momentum?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, momentum

In what sense can it be said that spacetime possesses momentum? Can an experiment be envisaged to test this question?

Answer (score 3):

In the case of an asymptotically flat spacetime (basically, one in which all of the matter is confined to a finite area of the spacetime), there is a quantity called the ADM Momentum that will tell you the total momentum contained in the spacetime, factoring both the matter and a contribution "from the geometry".  There are other schemes that let you do stuff like this if you have a timelike or null killing vector defined on a timelike or null 3-d surface.  Then, you can talk about the momentum (and energy) contained "within" this surface.  There is a review article on the topic [here](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-2009-4/)